# Developer Story tab leaves too little space for moderator-specific info

Tags: bug, design, developer-story, moderator-tools

With the new Developer Story tab, the space at the top is getting to crowded and the Mod tools lose out:

[image]

The *Account Info* & *Mod* menus, and the various status counters plus the meta-user and network account links all have been pushed down from their usual space.

When I use the dev tools to hide the developer tab (add a `display: none` style to that tab), things unbreak:

[image]

Not sure what the fix would be, but currently it is just ugly town up there.

Comment: Pff, show-off. "Look at all the important stuff I have". :p

Comment: @Bart: meep. Adam asked me to post a bug report :-/ I was all for keeping this to the Teachers Lounge!

Comment: You need to get a shorter name.

Comment: @Oded: Yeah, 4 characters should be enough for anybody, right?

Comment: Is the down vote for *meh, not important, don't fix this, don't spend dev time on it*? Or is it revenge ...

Comment: Hmm. Just dropping "dashboard" from "Mod dashboard" might be the quick/easy win here. Except that then there's two different things on the screen that are labeled "mod". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AdamLear What the difference between "Mod Dashboard" and "Mod"?

Comment: @Oriol The mod link brings up the menu of actions a moderator can take, Mod Dashboard shows a summary view of moderation-related information about the user in one handy spot.

Comment: Give your moderator status away. Saves you :D

Comment: I'm ont it, I'll suggest a design solution to the mods ASAP :)

Comment: What a moderator party down here.

Comment: Can mods edit **anyone**’s profile & settings?

Comment: @JF Yes. They need to be able to remove inappropriate content. Their access to/editing of profile data is logged for accountability.

Comment: Talk about first world problems;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak It's really irritating for the first-world-ers, though. The irritation on its own should be enough to make it at least a first-and-a-half world problem.

Comment: When I read the title, I thought there was some mod who wanted to add some flashing highlight to the dev story that they were mod on SO… “Look at me! I’m a mod!” – That wasn’t the case, good on you Martijn.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Comment: @Slate: fair enough; I would’ve done the same had I remembered this bug existing :-D